# Search in Outlook not working

Tags: exchange, outlook, search

This has been a confusing issue so I hope I write this correctly and it makes sense.
I've been having issues with an Exchange 2016 Server. The original problem was users not receiving their email. There have been a lot of issues with services not starting after a reboot. Working with MS support, we have most of the services running automatically. The tech had to add a key in the registry
HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\ServicesPipeTimeOut REG_DWORD Hex value 60000.
Before adding this key, users weren't receiving emails but they were able to use the search function and find emails from the server. After adding that key, services began starting automatically after reboot and users were receiving email, but we lost the search function.
We've also been having issue with some malware, I keep finding a MSIL\Chopper in virus scans intermittently. I'm not sure if all of this is related, but it's been very frustrating.
As far as steps to remedy the search issue, the index has been rebuilt and shows a healthy status. I've stopped and restarted the search services but this hasn't gotten anything moving. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any search errors when you search something in outlook client? If there are, what are these detailed error messages?

How many users encounter this issue? Could you try to migrate one user to another DB and check if this issue continues?

Here are some troubleshooting steps for your reference and hope it will be helpful to you. [Troubleshooting Outlook search issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshooting-outlook-search-issues-2556b11f-f4d8-46be-b0a7-de33a3f4f066)

Comment: It seems to be happening to all users across various versions of Outlook. We've been through all the steps in the troubleshooting link you posted and nothing works. The problem seems to be with Fast Search. IT will give the "we're having trouble fetching data from the server" message, but a full search seems to work fine.
It's been a weird issue. All the services on the server are running, I've checked the database and it's fine, I've even rebuilt the index just to see and nothing seems to help, but it looks like everything should be working.

Comment: I haven't tried moving users to a new DB yet, I'm not familiar with the process. Is there a guide to doing this?

Comment: Refer to the blog to migrate a mailbox to another DB : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/mailbox-servers/manage-mailbox-moves?view=exchserver-2016#use-the-eac-to-create-a-local-move-request